# What year and make BMX do I have?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Front back spring shocks 1970s. I'm sure is this a kawasaki BMX

---

EDIT from duplicate question.

[image]

After a lot of digging, I found that it is a 1975 Montgomery Ward Silver Fox

Comment: It does looks similar to BX-200, but all details are plain wrong: tob tube, rear triangle, dropouts. Doesn't look like Yamaha Moto-Bike either, but has similar features too.

Comment: I've never seen anything like it.

Comment: It looks home made, bodged together from tubing and spare parts.

Comment: @RoboKaren It does, rather. For example, the chain-stays don't pivot right at the bottom bracket, which means that the distance from the bottom bracket to the rear axle changes as the suspension flexes. Surely that's not going to work well without a derailleur to take up the slack in the chain?

Comment: Its no 1970s bike that's for sure - Suspension like this just wasn't a thing back then.   Is that front suspension in the fork?   Its a dual crown headset arrangement like a modern downhill bike.

Comment: The paint layout is interesting too - it appears to be painted black at the places where welding has happened.  I think its a scratch-built frame, possibly starting from a BMX frame as a base.   It needs a padded bench seat or a banana seat, and possibly some foot pegs for the passenger.   Also it needs brakes.

Comment: It's not home made few bike shop pros looked at it and not home made I found this number. N people  and when I got the bike paint was gone so I painted it that way in the pictures regular chain bmx chain works just takes a little longer one

Comment: FFJO6501 STAPED ON FRAME NEXT TO CRANK

Comment: On such an unusual bike that serial number could apply to a frame that was modified.  Rather than strictly home-made it looks like something built as a prototype or for fun by someone who could build custom frames.

Comment: I thought the large flat "carrier" part was the frame for holding a seat.  Never saw the seat tube in the original photos.  Now it makes a bit more sense, but I'm also imagining a bike with a "weight-bench" seat :)

Comment: @Criggie re dual crown fork - that arrangement has been used in motorcycles for decades, and may have been copied from that practice

Comment: @Criggie - It is a fairly primitive suspension.  External coil springs and likely lacking damping.  (In the top picture it appears that the rear suspension has been updated.)

Comment: @DonaldStigney, if you found the frame model, I'd advise to put that as an answer and accept it. Answering your own questions is acceptable here.

Comment: I found the frame model 1st a 1975 montgomery wards silver fox

Answer (score 3):

It's 1975 Montgomery Wards Silver Fox.

[image]
This is a pretty nice bike thanks for helping me

Comment: Nice pic - that bike looks really back-tippy ... wheelie-happy if you like.

Answer (score 0):

1975 Wards SILVER FOX. Those are the stock forks. As for CRIGGIE, You don't know. Have you seen the Yamaha  & Kawasaki moto bikes? Same style fork.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This appears to have already been suggested and accepted as an answer; please don't post duplicate answers, or post answers to make comments.  You might want to take the [tour].